# Exporting and importing a mysqldump from within a mysql CLI heredocument

Tags: mysql, console, database, oracle-database, dump

The following code drops a DB user and a DB instance by the name of `test`, if both exists, then creates an authorized, all privileged DB user and a DB instance with the same name (also `test`).

```
mysql -u root -p <<-MYSQL
    DROP user IF EXISTS 'test'@'localhost'; SELECT user FROM mysql.user;
    DROP database IF EXISTS test; show databases;

    CREATE user 'test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '${psw}';
    CREATE database test;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* TO test@localhost;
MYSQL
```

I lack too things in this code:

1. Exporting `${domain}` into a `{$domain}.sql` mysqldump.
2. Importing `${domain}.sql` mysqldump into the `test` DB database.

How could I add these two actions but **inside** the heredocument? I don't want them to be different actions outside the heredocument (what requires entering username and password again and again), rather, I need them as regular mysql queries inside the heredocument, coming right after the last GRANT query.

Comment: If you do not want to enter multiple times password maybe you can read password once and pass it to multiple commands: `echo -n "Enter root mysql password:"` `read -s DBROOT_PASS` `mysql -u root -p$DBROOT_PASS -e "$SQL"`. I personally use one file with mysql root credentials with only root access and execute mysql commands like `mysql --defaults-extra-file=/root/.my.cnf dbname  -e "$SQL"`. It doesn't require any password only root access.

Comment: This is a main part of the correct solution dear @motivast and I invite you to write an answer with it.

Comment: @motivast you might be able to save the day here as well (I'm quite stuck with that): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47744613/mysql-console-backup-import-fails-in-correct-directory-with-correct-password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. Exporting

Unfortunately, [*mysql shell*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-commands.html) can't dump database contents like *mysqldump* does, so it's impossible to execute SQL queries and dump database in one call to *mysql* or *mysqldump*. However you can:

**a)** Grant user `test` access to the `${domain}` database:

```
mysql -u root -p <<-MYSQL
    ...
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${domain}.* TO 'test'@'localhost';
    GRANT GRANT OPTION ON ${domain}.* TO 'test'@'localhost';
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
MYSQL
```

subsequently call:

```
mysqldump -u test -p"${psw}" "${domain}" >domain.sql
```

and finally call:

```
mysql -u test -p"${psw}" <<-MYSQL
    REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${domain}.* FROM 'test'@'localhost';
    REVOKE GRANT OPTION ON ${domain}.* FROM 'test'@'localhost';
MYSQL
```

No need to enter the password again as it's passed in command line. However passing the password in command line is insecure so you may consider using `expect` or creation of my.cnf with user/password settings and referring to it with `--defaults-extra-file=` as [motivast](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/264934/motivast) suggested.

**b)** You can read the root password in the beginning of your script and then use it in subsequent mysql calls (this described in [motivast](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/264934/motivast) comment):

```
read -s -p 'Enter password: ' root_psw
echo
my_cnf=`tempfile -s .cnf -m 400`
echo "[mysql] >${my_cnf}
echo "user=root" >>${my_cnf}
echo "password=${root_psw}" >>${my_cnf}

# Delete the password file after this script finish (even in case of error)
cleanup_my_cnf { rm "${my_cnf}"; }
trap cleanup_my_cnf INT TERM EXIT

mysql --defaults-extra-file="${my_cnf}" <<-MYSQL
    ...
MYSQL

mysqldump --defaults-extra-file="${my_cnf}" "${domain}" >domain.sql
```

**c)** If you only need to dump table structure and you know table names, you could use the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` SQL:

```
mysql -u root -p <<-MYSQL
    ...
    use ${domain};
    tee domain.dump;
    SHOW CREATE TABLE table1;
    SHOW CREATE TABLE table2;
MYSQL
```

But this is too exotic and domain.dump would need a bit of editing afterwards.

### 2. Importing

That's pretty easy with source command (same as in the bash):

```
mysql -u root -p <<-MYSQL
    ...
    use test;
    source ${domain}.sql;
MYSQL
```